# Design patterns for Caching Images in a MVC?

Tags: php, image, model-view-controller, caching, single-responsibility-principle

I'm designing an image cache system that will be used in an MVC CMS. The main purpose of the image cacher is to modify images: scale, crop, etc and cache them in the client site.

I have created an image cache Model and Mapper that interact with the Database, to keep track of the images and know what kind of actions have been applied to them (scale, crop, etc).

In addition to the Model and Mapper I have created a ImageCacher Class that is used by the API  to manage the Model and image creation based on arguments passed by the client site, this class creates the images and generates the links to the images for the View.

A coworker argued that I need to include the functionality of this last Class inside the Model, as the bulk of the logic should go in the model.

I respectfully disagree with him since I feel the model's responsibility is to deal with the information about the images cached at the database level, and the responsibility of the ImageCacher Class is to create the url/image that we will be caching (keeping the single responsibility principle). In addition to this I believe that a model should not have Presentation-related features, like creating or showing images.

Does anyone have any insight on this? is there a particular design pattern that would make this division of tasks clear and and the image cacher reusable? Should I add all the logic in the Model?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

IMO it's too much effort for a questionable outcome. You're building all the logic, spend CPU and SQL resources to find out which client has what images cached, while client side cache is an unreliable way to store things. I don't know the nature of your application, but if more than one client uses same image files (resized, cropped, etc) than it's counter-economic to store them client side in the first place.

Re. your question, IMO model is the place to store logic, as it's easier to reuse it when it's in model.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, once the image has been cached in the client side we do not contact the server (no Queries to the DB are done) as long as the image exist. if there are no image in the client, we call the server and request an image to be transferred. In the other hand if the image is changed in the server, the server 'pings' the client and request the image to be deleted, so the next time the client tries to open the image it will request it from the server. I believe we reduce in this way the number of calls to the server and Queries. is very unlikely that the same image will be used

Comment: Why don't you allow browser / client to do the job? If you set cache headers the right way your client will not load physical files every time. When your browser gets "Status Code:304 Not Modified" it will not load them again.